# Format-Table on Array of Hash Tables

Tags: powershell, formatting

How do you format an array of hash tables with the [Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx) cmdlet?

**Example:**

```
$table = @( @{ColumnA="Able";    ColumnB=1},
            @{ColumnA="Baker";   ColumnB=2},
            @{ColumnA="Charlie"; ColumnB=3} )
$table | Format-Table
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ColumnA                        ColumnB
----                           -----
Able                           1
Baker                          2
Charlie                        3
```

***Actual*** Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
ColumnA                        Able
ColumnB                        1
ColumnA                        Baker
ColumnB                        2
ColumnA                        Charlie
ColumnB                        3
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Using Powershell V4:

```
$table = @( @{ColumnA="Able";    ColumnB=1},
            @{ColumnA="Baker";   ColumnB=2},
            @{ColumnA="Charlie"; ColumnB=3} )

$table | ForEach {[PSCustomObject]$_} | Format-Table -AutoSize


ColumnA ColumnB
------- -------
Able          1
Baker         2
Charlie       3
```

V2 solution:

```
$(foreach ($ht in $table)
 {new-object PSObject -Property $ht}) | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Do you need a V2-specific solution?

Comment: It would be nice, but I can upgrade to V4 if that is what it takes. Can you do it in V2?

Comment: PS2 way shorter: `$table| % { new-object PSObject -Property $_}`

Comment: Adding Format-Table back to @majkinetor solution, makes formatting nicer

`$table| % { new-object PSObject -Property $_} | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: Thanks! When my `$table` contained only one element, though, there was an error, so I had to tweak it a little `@($table)`

Comment: I found the provided foreach syntax a little awkward, but it pointed me in the right direction. -- I ended up using this syntax `$table | % { [PSCustomObject]$_ } | Format-Table`

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Discovered an alternative way of doing this:

```
$table | Select-Object -Property (
    $table.Keys | Group-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
```

But compared to @mjolinor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874563/2410990), doing this is:

- More verbose
- Slower, by about an order of magnitude, based on quick test of 10,000 elements

Casting to `[PSCustomObject]` seems to be the right way to go.