# Format-Table for array of hashtables

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the `Format-Table` command to output an array of hash tables of all files checked out from our TFS repo.

My code thus far:

```
$arr = @();
#Take the string from the tf command, parse it and build an array of hash tables
(tf stat /recursive /user:* /format:detailed | Select-String -Pattern '^\$' -NotMatch | Select -SkipLast 3 | Out-String) -split '(\r\n){2}' | ForEach-Object {
    $ht = @{};
    if ($_ -ne '') {
        $str = $_ | Out-String;
        $str -split '\r?\n'| ForEach-Object {
            $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*:\s*';
            #Write-Host $key, $Value;
            try {
                $ht.Add($key, $value);
            } catch [ArgumentException] {
                Write-Host "Caught exception";
            }
        }
        $arr += ($ht);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Looks like I'm erroring out here.

```
$arr.ForEach({[PSCustomObject]$_}) | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Full Error:

```
Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type
"System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives+InternalPSCustomObject". Error: "Cannot process argument because the
value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again."
At C:\Dev\Tools\powershell\Convert-TfsOutput.ps1:21 char:15
+ $arr.ForEach({[PSCustomObject]$_}) | Format-Table -AutoSize
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastConstructorException
```

**Edit2**

Here is sample output when i replace the above line with:

```
$arr.ForEach({ $_ | Out-String })

Name                           Value
----                           -----
  Workspace                    work1
  Date                         {Wednesday, September 5, 2018 1, 38, 48 PM}
  Local item                   file1
  File type                    Windows-1252
  User                         user1
  Lock                         none

  Change                       edit




Name                           Value
----                           -----
  Workspace                    work2
  Date                         {Monday, September 10, 2018 12, 14, 56 PM}
  Local item                   file2
  User                         user2
  Lock                         none

  Change                       edit
```

**Edit 3**

Output of the below command

```
Write-Host $str;

  User       : User1
  Date       : Wednesday, September 5, 2018 1:38:48 PM
  Lock       : none
  Change     : edit
  Workspace  : Work1
  Local item : File1
  File type  : Windows-1252




  User       : User2
  Date       : Monday, September 10, 2018 12:14:56 PM
  Lock       : none
  Change     : edit
  Workspace  : Work2
  Local item : File2
```

Would like the output in a tabular format with rows below the column names:

```
Workspace | Date | Local item | File type | User | Lock | Change
```

Tried to use the code in another answer but it does not output correctly.
[Format-Table on Array of Hash Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874464/format-table-on-array-of-hash-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your hashtables to custom objects before passing them to `Format-Table`.

```
... | Where-Object { $_ } | ForEach-Object {
    $ht = @{};
    ($_ | Out-String) -split '\r?\n'| ForEach-Object {
        ...
    }
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $ht
} | Format-Table
```

---

**Edit:** Looks like your input data has blank lines which lead to keys with empty strings in your hashtables, which then cause the error you observed, because objects can't have a property with an empty string for a name.

Change your hashtable/object creation to something like this:

```
... | Where-Object { $_ } | ForEach-Object {
    $ht = ($_ | Out-String).Trim() -replace '\s+:\s+', '=' |
          ConvertFrom-StringData
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $ht
} | Format-Table
```

Comment: $pso = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $ht;
        $arr += ($pso);
    }
}

$arr.ForEach({[PSObject]$_}) | Format-Table -AutoSize

Tried this and getting an exception:
New-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name"
argument and run the operation again.

Comment: @wonderstruck80 What is `[PSObject]$_` supposed to accomplish? You already have a list of custom objects at that point. Also, don't append to an array in a loop.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to properly format a comment. Looks like i'm erroring out on creating the new object and am unsure why.

Comment: This led me to a solution to the initial question.