# How to create PowerShell datastructure that works well with format-table

Tags: powershell, class, formattable

**When I do "$states2 | ft" I get this:**

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
NY                             State
AZ                             State
```

**When I would rather get this:**

```
Name    Acres   Population   Founded  FullName
----    -----   ----------   -------  --------
NY        50           100      1645  New York
AK       100           512      1745  Alaska
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

**Here is my data structure in the form of a class:**

```
class State {
    [Int64]$Acres
    [Int64]$Population
    [Int16]$Founded
    [string]$FullName
    }

$States2 = @{}
$States2.AK = [State] @{Population = 512; Founded = 1745; Acres = 100; FullName = "Alaska"}

$States2.NY = [State]::new()
$States2.NY.Acres       = 50
$States2.NY.Population = 100
$States2.NY.Founded    = 1652
$States2.NY.FullName   = "New York"
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: This isn't the complete answer, but it's fairly similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874464/format-table-on-array-of-hash-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make the abbreviated name part of the class definition:

```
class State {
    [string]Name
    [Int64]$Acres
    [Int64]$Population
    [Int16]$Founded
    [string]$FullName
}

$States2 = @{}
$States2.AK = [State] @{Name = "AK"; Population = 512; Founded = 1745; Acres = 100; FullName = "Alaska"}

$States2.NY = [State]::new()
$States2.NY.Name       = "NY" 
$States2.NY.Acres      = 50
$States2.NY.Population = 100
$States2.NY.Founded    = 1652
$States2.NY.FullName   = "New York"
```

If you only want the show the *values* in the `$States2` hashtable, do:

```
$States2.Values |Format-Table
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mathias!

Comment: @chris You're welcome! If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left