# Format an array of hashtables as table with Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, format, hashtable

I wish to display an array of hastables as a Table. I found several threads dealing with this issue, but so far no solution has worked for me (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874464/format-table-on-array-of-hash-tables) and [here](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/how-do-i-format-array-of-hastables-into-a-table/)).

My array consists of 18 hashtables in this form:

```
Array = @(
    @{Company=1} 
    @{Company=2} 
    @{Company=3} 
    @{Contact=X} 
    @{Contact=Y} 
    @{Contact=Y} 
    @{Country=A} 
    @{Country=B} 
    @{Country=C} 
)
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
Company Contact Country
------------------------------
1                   X                 A
2                   Y                 B
3                   Z                 C
```

I've tried the following:

```
$Array | ForEach-Object { New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $_ } | Format-Table
```

That displays the following:

```
Company
----------
1
2
3
```

A `Format-List` works better; I then get this:

```
Company: 1 2 3
Contact: X Y Z
Country: A B C
```

Is there any way to accomplish my desired output?

Comment: Please provide a working data set as example...

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following if you want to work with CSV data and custom objects:

```
$Array = @(
    @{Company=1} 
    @{Company=2} 
    @{Company=3} 
    @{Contact='X'} 
    @{Contact='Y'} 
    @{Contact='Z'} 
    @{Country='A'} 
    @{Country='B'} 
    @{Country='C'} 
)

$keys = $Array.Keys | Get-Unique
$data = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Array.($Keys[0]).Count; $i++) {
    ($Keys | Foreach-Object { $Array.$_[$i] }) -join ','
}
($Keys -join ','),$data | ConvertFrom-Csv | Format-Table
```

**Explanation:**

Since `$Array` is an array of hash tables, then the `.Keys` property will return all the keys of those hash tables. Since we only care about unique keys when building our object, `Get-Unique` is used to remove duplicates.

`$Array.($Keys[0]).Count` counts the number of items in a group. `$Keys[0]` here will be `Company`. So it returns the number of hash tables (3) that contain the key `Company`.

`$Array.Company` for example returns all values from the hash tables that contain the key `Company`. The `Foreach-Object` loops through each unique key's value at a particular index (`$i`). Once each key-value is read at a particular index, the values are joined by a comma.

When the loop completes, `($Keys -join ','),$data` outputs the data in CSV format, which is piped into `ConvertFrom-Csv` to create a custom object.

**Note:** that if your data contains commas, you may want to consider the alternative method below.

---

Alernatively, you can work with hash tables and custom objects with the following:

```
$Array = @(
    @{Company=1} 
    @{Company=2} 
    @{Company=3} 
    @{Contact='X'} 
    @{Contact='Y'} 
    @{Contact='Z'} 
    @{Country='A'} 
    @{Country='B'} 
    @{Country='C'} 
)
$keys = $Array.Keys | Get-Unique
$data = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Array.($Keys[0]).Count; $i++) {
    $hash = [ordered]@{}
    $Keys | Foreach-Object { $hash.Add($_,$Array.$_[$i]) }
    [pscustomobject]$hash
}
$data | Format-Table
```